# selenium error [attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities' selenium ]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
'''from selenium import webdriver 
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager 

browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())   
browser.get("https://elzero.org")'''
```

It always gives me this error

```
attribute error 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities' selenium
```

even though all packages are installed correctly! I have double checked all possible packages installations.
**new erorr**
"""

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 

 File "D:\Desktop\python\selenuiem.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())   
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 319, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 374, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 397, in _request
    resp = self._conn.request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 144, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\_request_methods.py", line 279, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 433, in urlopen    
    conn = self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 304, in connection_from_host
    return self.connection_from_context(request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 329, in connection_from_context
    return self.connection_from_pool_key(pool_key, request_context=request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 352, in connection_from_pool_key
    pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port, request_context=request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 266, in _new_pool  
    return pool_cls(host, port, **request_context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 196, in __init__
    timeout = Timeout.from_float(timeout)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 186, in from_float
    return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 115, in __init__  
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, "connect")
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Mosaed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\timeout.py", line 152, in _validate_timeout
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Timeout value connect was <object object at 0x000002BD33FE4540>, but it must be an int, float or None.
```

"""

Comment: Can you add the full error message to the post by editing it? Also next time wrap any code in '''s to mark it as code and make the post more readable. Take some time to properly format/write your post and people will react better to it.

Comment: As of Selenium 4.6, you no longer need to use a separate driver manager library because one is included in Selenium, see [this article](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager). You can remove all driver manager references and change your Chromedriver instance to simply, `browser = webdriver.Chrome()`. See if that fixes the issue.